# Failed to Load Application Context after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade to `spring-boot 2.2`/`Spring 5.2`. We are using the reactive WebClient in combination with plain JDBC.

After upgrading we receive the following error:-

> Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/ReactiveTransactionManager

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager

What is the path we need to follow to upgrade in the case where `@transactional` is used and reactive streams is on the classpath?

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml

Comment: I am using a gradle project. Do you know the possible solution to this issue.

Comment: What are your current versions?

Comment: Then please show your build.gradle

Comment: @Boris Current version of all the spring boot packages is 2.1.1.RELEASE and I am upgrading them to 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: @ Simon Martinelli  right now I can't post my build.gradle ...but if you have any possible solution to this problem kindly let me know.

Comment: Are you specifying the version of `springframework` explicitly?

Comment: @Boris yes I am specifying it explicitly

Comment: You do not need to provide a version for the dependency in your build configuration, as Spring Boot [manages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-build-systems) that for you. Also what is your Gradle version?

Comment: @Boris but i have to provide the vrsion of spring packages like webflux , undertow etc .. other wise how will it get to know which version to ....moreover I want to use latest version of spring packages.

Comment: No, for WebFlux you should use `spring-boot-starter-webflux` [application starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter), for Undertow it's `spring-boot-starter-undertow` and so on. When you upgrade Spring Boot itself, these dependencies are upgraded as well in a consistent way.

Comment: @Boris Yes I am using in that way only and upgrading all of them to 2.2.2 from 2.1.1 .. stil I am gettting that issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204355/discussion-between-boris-and-harsh-garg).

Comment: This https://www.programmersought.com/article/35195094551/ also discusses this problem. There the solution was to upgrade spring-tx from 5.1.x to 5.2.x as the latter has the class.